Discrepancy Between SQL Server and Oracle months_between Function Outputs
I'm working on a project where I need to calculate the number of months between two dates in both SQL Server (using Synapse) and Oracle. I've created a user-defined function in SQL Server to replicate Oracle's months_between function, but I'm encountering slight discrepancies in the outputs which accumulate over time and by extension creating massive difference when calculation metrics.
My Attempt:
CREATE FUNCTION [TFM].[UDF_MONTHS_BETWEEN] (
    @start_date_p [DATE]
    ,@end_date_p [DATE]
    )
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count_v FLOAT;
    DECLARE @daysinmonth_v FLOAT;
    DECLARE @dayofmonth_v FLOAT;

    -- Count whole months 
    SET @count_v = DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@start_date_p), MONTH(@start_date_p), 1)), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@end_date_p), MONTH(@end_date_p), 1));
    -- Days in start month 
    SET @daysinmonth_v = DAY(EOMONTH(@start_date_p));
    -- Get fractional start month 
    SET @dayofmonth_v = DAY(@start_date_p);
    SET @count_v = @count_v + ((@daysinmonth_v - (@dayofmonth_v - 1)) * (1.0 / @daysinmonth_v));
    -- Days in end month 
    SET @daysinmonth_v = DAY(EOMONTH(@end_date_p));
    -- Get fractional end month 
    SET @dayofmonth_v = DAY(@end_date_p);
    SET @count_v = @count_v + ((@dayofmonth_v - 1) * (1.0 / @daysinmonth_v));

    RETURN ABS(@count_v);
END





Test Case
Input Dates
Sql server Output
Oracle Output




Test 1
'6/28/2024', '7/27/2024'
0.938
0.9677419354838709677419354838709677419355


Test 2
'4/28/2024', '7/27/2024'
2.9387
2.96774193548387096774193548387096774194



I need them to be as close a possible.
Code to test :
sql server : SELECT TFM.UDF_MONTHS_BETWEEN('4/28/2024','7/27/2024') 
oracle : SELECT ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN('28-APR-24','27-JUL-24')) FROM DUAL;


I must admit, calculating the "months" as a decimal value feels like it's less than ideal. Considering you are storing the values as dates, why not use the number of days; 29 days is much less ambiguous on the time length than 0.966666 months (when a month can be, 28-31 days long).

You didn't ask any question in your question. If you need help porting some oracle functions, you either need to specify how it works or contact some expensive consultants, this is not a free code writing consultancy

The Oracle documentation says how the function works. Specifically, "If date1 and date2 are either the same days of the month or both last days of months, then the result is always an integer. Otherwise Oracle Database calculates the fractional portion of the result based on a 31-day month..." so your SQL Server version would need to implement the same rules.

As pointed out by @AlexPoole, the Oracle documentation for MONTHS_BETWEEN states:

MONTHS_BETWEEN returns number of months between dates date1 and date2. The month and the last day of the month are defined by the parameter NLS_CALENDAR. If date1 is later than date2, then the result is positive. If date1 is earlier than date2, then the result is negative. If date1 and date2 are either the same days of the month or both last days of months, then the result is always an integer. Otherwise Oracle Database calculates the fractional portion of the result based on a 31-day month and considers the difference in time components date1 and date2.

So you need to:

set the days of the month to 31 for all months (and not to the actual days of the month);
remove ABS as the result should be negative when date1 is after date2;
check if the day of the month are both the last day of the month and, if so, return an integer; and
the Oracle function is MONTHS_BETWEEN(end_date, start_date) but your function has the arguments swapped.

Like this:
CREATE FUNCTION [TFM].[UDF_MONTHS_BETWEEN] (
    @end_date_p [DATE],
    @start_date_p [DATE]
) RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @count_v INT;
  DECLARE @dayofsmonth_v INT;
  DECLARE @dayofemonth_v INT;

  -- Count whole months 
  SET @count_v = DATEDIFF(
                   MONTH,
                   DATETRUNC(MONTH, @start_date_p),
                   DATETRUNC(MONTH, @end_date_p)
                 );

  SET @dayofsmonth_v = DAY(@start_date_p);
  SET @dayofemonth_v = DAY(@end_date_p);

  IF (
    @dayofsmonth_v = @dayofemonth_v
    OR (
         @dayofsmonth_v = DAY(EOMONTH(@start_date_p))
      AND @dayofemonth_v = DAY(EOMONTH(@end_date_p))
    )
  )
    RETURN @count_v;

  RETURN @count_v + (@dayofemonth_v - @dayofsmonth_v)/31.0E0;
END

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE tests (
  test_case  VARCHAR(20),
  start_date DATE,
  end_date   DATE,
  oracle_output NUMERIC(30,26)
);

INSERT INTO tests (test_case, start_date, end_date, oracle_output)
VALUES (
  'Test 1',
  '2024-06-28',
  '2024-07-27',
  0.967741935483870967741935
),
(
  'Test 2',
  '2024-04-28',
  '2024-07-27',
  2.967741935483870967741935
),
(
  'Test 3',
  '2024-07-27',
  '2024-04-28',
  -2.967741935483870967741935
),
(
  'Test 4',
  '2024-07-31',
  '2024-04-30',
  -3
),
(
  'Test 5',
  '2024-06-20',
  '2024-07-27',
  1.2258064516129032258064516
);

Then:
SELECT test_case,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       [TFM].[UDF_MONTHS_BETWEEN](end_date, start_date) AS sql_server_output,
       oracle_output
FROM   tests;

Outputs:



test_case
start_date
end_date
sql_server_output
oracle_output




Test 1
2024-06-28
2024-07-27
0.967741935483871
0.96774193548387096774193500


Test 2
2024-04-28
2024-07-27
2.96774193548387
2.96774193548387096774193500


Test 3
2024-07-27
2024-04-28
-2.96774193548387
-2.96774193548387096774193500


Test 4
2024-07-31
2024-04-30
-3
-3.00000000000000000000000000


Test 5
2024-06-20
2024-07-27
1.2258064516129
1.22580645161290322580645160



SQL Server fiddle Oracle fiddle

thank you very much .
the calculation of count_v needs to change a little or will be getting a conversion error.
SET @count_v = DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @start_date_p), 0), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @end_date_p), 0))
